# Normalize decimals values to integer number (uniquely) in matlab

Tags: matlab, normalization

Any way to do this? Let's say I have `A=[0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4]`, then after normalize, `A_norm=[1 2 3 4]`, based on the 'importance' each of the value, that mean 0.4 will be the largest (4 assigned) and 0.1 will be the least (1 assigned).

You might suggest to just `A_norm=A*10`, but do note that the number can be any numbers with up to more than 10 significant figures. And not to round to their nearest integer numbers too using command like `floor` `ceil` and `round`.

Thanks!

Comment: Which result do you want in case of duplicate values in `A`?

Comment: In case duplicate values of A exist, the 'importance value' should be the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can just use the [third output](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html#outputarg_ic) of `unique`, which is the *indexes* of sorted `A`. note that if you'll use the [`'stable'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html#inputarg_setOrder) option it will be the indexes of the *unsorted* `A`, so don't:

```
A=[0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.005 0.4];
[~,~,A_norm] = unique(A);
A_norm = A_norm.'

A_norm =

     2     3     4     5     1     5
```

Comment: It may be useful to use the same names as in the question and explain how your solution works.

Comment: Why do you use `.'` instead of `'`?

Comment: thanks for the comments @m7913d, I edited my answer accordingly. `.'` is the transpose operator (unlike `'` which is the complex conjugate transpose operator). I rarely use it and I know it's only indexes here (which have to be real number), but others here commented about it so I adopted `.'` for SO.